# Android Widget onReceive not Triggered by Button Clicks

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, android-widget, android-pendingintent

I am facing an issue with my Android widget. The onReceive method is automatically triggered when the widget is placed on the home screen, but it doesn't get called when I click the buttons with ids (button1, button2) or the ImageView with the ID @+id/imageRightOfButtons.

I have set up PendingIntent with setOnClickPendingIntent for 2 butttons and imageview in the onUpdate method, but the onReceive method is not getting invoked.

NewAppWidget.java

```
public class NewAppWidget extends AppWidgetProvider {
    public static final String ACTION_BUTTON1_CLICK = "com.yourapp.ACTION_BUTTON1_CLICK";
    public static final String ACTION_BUTTON2_CLICK = "com.yourapp.ACTION_BUTTON2_CLICK";
    private final Long callBackDispatcherId=4944696197L;
    FlutterEngine backgroundFlutterEngine;
    DartExecutor executor;
    BinaryMessenger binaryMessenger;
    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
        Log.d("NewAPPWidget", "latest onUpdate method");
        for (int appWidgetId : appWidgetIds) {
            RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.new_app_widget);
            Intent button1Intent = new Intent(context, NewAppWidget.class);
            button1Intent.setAction(ACTION_BUTTON1_CLICK);
            PendingIntent button1PendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, button1Intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE );
            views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.button1, button1PendingIntent);
            Intent button2Intent = new Intent(context, NewAppWidget.class);
            button2Intent.setAction(ACTION_BUTTON2_CLICK);
            PendingIntent button2PendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 1, button2Intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE);
            views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.button2, button2PendingIntent);
            views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.imageRightOfButtons, getPendingIntent(context,appWidgetId));
            appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
        }
    }
static void updateAppWidget(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int appWidgetId) {
    Log.d("NewAPPWidget", "  updateAppWidget");
    Intent refreshIntent = new Intent(context, NewAppWidget.class);
    refreshIntent.setAction(AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE);
    refreshIntent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS, new int[]{appWidgetId});
    RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.new_app_widget);
    String currentTime = DateFormat.getTimeInstance(DateFormat.SHORT).format(new Date());
    String currentDate = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.SHORT).format(new Date());
    views.setTextViewText(R.id.text_time, "last updated on "+currentTime);
    views.setTextViewText(R.id.text_date, currentDate);
    appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
}

    public static PendingIntent getPendingIntent(Context context, int appWidgetId) {
        Log.d("NewAPPWidget", "get PendingIntent");
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, NewAppWidget.class);
        intent.setAction("com.example.myapp.DATA_UPDATE");
        intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetId);

        return PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 2, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        super.onReceive(context, intent);
        int clickedButtonBackgroundColor = Color.parseColor("#FD681C");
        int unclickedButtonBackgroundColor = Color.WHITE;
        int unclickedButtonTextColor = Color.parseColor("#FD681C");
        Log.d("NewAPPWidget", "OnReceive method");
        Log.d("NewAPPWidget", "Intent name is "+intent.getAction());
        RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.new_app_widget);

        if (ACTION_BUTTON1_CLICK.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            Log.d("NewAPPWidget", "button1");
            updateButtonBackground(context, views, R.id.button1, clickedButtonBackgroundColor, Color.WHITE);
            updateButtonBackground(context, views, R.id.button2, unclickedButtonBackgroundColor, unclickedButtonTextColor);

        } else if (ACTION_BUTTON2_CLICK.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            Log.d("NewAPPWidget", "button2");
            updateButtonBackground(context, views, R.id.button2, clickedButtonBackgroundColor, Color.WHITE);
            updateButtonBackground(context, views, R.id.button1, unclickedButtonBackgroundColor, unclickedButtonTextColor);
        }
        else if (AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE.equals(intent.getAction()) || "com.example.myapp.DATA_UPDATE".equals(intent.getAction())) {
            Log.d("kkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkk","update hfdhgkjhjkdhgkdshgkjsdhkjsdhgkjsdhgsdhbgksdhbgkbgkjsdbgkdsjgbmjh");
            AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
            fetchDataFromApp(context);
            String arg1 = intent.getStringExtra("arg1");
            String arg2 = intent.getStringExtra("arg2");
            String arg3 = intent.getStringExtra("arg3");
            int[] appWidgetIds = intent.getIntArrayExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS);
            if (appWidgetIds != null) {
                for (int appWidgetId : appWidgetIds) {
                    updateAppWidget(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetId);
                }
            }
            updateAppWidgetWithData(context, arg1, arg2, arg3);
        }

    }

    private void updateButtonBackground(Context context, RemoteViews views, int buttonId, int backgroundColor, int textColor) {
        views.setInt(buttonId, "setBackgroundColor", backgroundColor);
        Log.d("NewAPPWidget","updateButtonBackground");
        if (buttonId == R.id.button2) {
            Log.d("NewAPPWidget", "button2");
            views.setTextColor(R.id.button1, Color.WHITE);
            views.setTextColor(R.id.button2, textColor);
            views.setInt(R.id.button1, "setBackgroundResource", R.drawable.inner_switch_button);
            views.setInt(R.id.button2,"setBackgroundColor", android.R.color.transparent);
        } else if (buttonId == R.id.button1) {
            Log.d("NewAPPWidget", "button1");
            views.setTextColor(R.id.button2, Color.WHITE);
            views.setTextColor(R.id.button1, textColor);
            views.setInt(R.id.button2, "setBackgroundResource", R.drawable.inner_switch_button);
            views.setInt(R.id.button1,"setBackgroundColor", android.R.color.transparent);
        }
        AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context).updateAppWidget(new ComponentName(context, NewAppWidget.class), views);
    }

    private void updateAppWidgetWithData(Context context, String arg1, String arg2, String arg3) {
        Log.d("NewAPPWidget","updateAppWidgetWithData");
        AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
        int[] appWidgetIds = appWidgetManager.getAppWidgetIds(new ComponentName(context, NewAppWidget.class));
        for (int appWidgetId : appWidgetIds) {
            RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.new_app_widget);
            views.setTextViewText(R.id.text_arg1, arg1);
            views.setTextViewText(R.id.text_arg2, arg2);
            views.setTextViewText(R.id.text_arg3, arg3);

            appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
        }
    }

    public void fetchDataFromApp(@NonNull Context context){
        /* Some Implementation */
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<receiver
            android:name=".NewAppWidget"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
                <action android:name="com.example.myapp.DATA_UPDATE" />
                <action android:name="com.yourapp.ACTION_BUTTON1_CLICK" />
                <action android:name="com.yourapp.ACTION_BUTTON2_CLICK" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
                android:resource="@xml/new_app_widget_info" />
        </receiver>
```

new_app_widget.xml

```
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="160dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/imageLeftOfOutbound"
            android:foreground="@drawable/darker_grey_border"
            android:layout_margin="6dp">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button1"
                android:layout_width="70dp"
                android:layout_height="25dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/inner_switch_button"
                android:text="Outbound"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="10sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button2"
                android:layout_width="70dp"
                android:layout_height="25dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@id/button1"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:elevation="0dp"
                android:text="Inbound"
                android:textColor="#FD681C"
                android:textSize="10sp" />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageRightOfButtons"
            android:layout_width="19dp"
            android:layout_height="19dp"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:src="@drawable/proper_refresh_icon" />
```